# Except "error: nothing to repeat" or "error: multiple repeat" in try/except block

Tags: python, regex, python-2.7, error-handling

**EDIT:** I am handling hundreds of thousands of pairs of strings for a substitution. Some turn out to have special characters in them and I need to handle these solutions on the fly when they occur.

When I try

```
re.sub('++', 'C++', 'replace ++ in string')
```

I get the error

```
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "<pyshell#202>", line 1, in <module>
    re.sub(r'++', 'C++', 'replace ++ in string')
  File "C:\Users\Me\AppData\Local\Continuum\Anaconda2\lib\re.py", line 155, in sub
    return _compile(pattern, flags).sub(repl, string, count)
  File "C:\Users\Me\AppData\Local\Continuum\Anaconda2\lib\re.py", line 251, in _compile
    raise error, v # invalid expression
error: nothing to repeat
```

Is there a way to specify that I am looking for this error specifically in a try/except block? Something like `except "NothingToRepeatError":`

I mentioned multiple repeat error in the title as well because I came across it while trying to solve the nothing to repeat error.

Comment: "+" is a meta-character; you need to escape it with a backslash.

Comment: Sorry, I was not specific enough. I am doing this substitution with many pairs of strings that I do not know beforehand. I am looking for a general solution for this. I will add an edit.

Comment: The solution is in the linked thread. Use `re.escape`. `re.sub(re.escape('++'), 'C++', 'replace ++ in string')`. Or if the replacements are literal, use `str.replace` (`s = s.replace('++', 'C++')`).

Comment: @WiktorStribiżew Do you know about the performance of re.escape()? My example was pretty trivial, but i'll need to do this on about 10GB of text data for hundreds of thousands, likely millions, of pairs.

Comment: Again, if you deal with *literal text replacements*, use `str.replace`. It will be the most efficient. Else, you just have to use `re.escape`.